# Sending data through Telnet-established connection on windows command line

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, telnet

I have connected to an outside server using telnet on windows cmd. I have a program written in Ruby running on my local machine whose output needs to be passed as a command in the server running. How do I go about with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. A telnet connection is pretty easy to do in Ruby though, just make your own connection.